# Update addon to 1.3.2 RELEASE

Tags: spring-roo

we have created some addons in 1.1.5 RELEASE. Since we are migrating from windows to linux environment, we saw that there are some bugs that ocurr in linux running the addons with this release. So in response to a created issue, we got recommended to use the latest release (that is assumed to include fixes for some bugs including this in particular that is happening to us: https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/ROO-3684). In order to make it compatible our addons to 1.3.2 RELEASE is it possible to update these ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to archive it: There are a lot of changes between this versions.

Without know the functionality provided by your add-ons, I only can think in two ways to migrate your add-ons to the new Spring Roo version:

1. Modify the dependencies of your *pom.xml* files and fix all problems you found.
2. Create a new add-on project using command [`addon create`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/simple-addons.html) of new Spring Roo version and migrate functionality in parts.

IMHO the second way could be *lower painful* than first one but it depends on your add-on complexity.

Good luck!